# Excel changing the date when pressing enter

Tags: excel

I have a custom format `dd-mmm-yy` on a cell

When i enter `01/06/2015` or `01-JUN-15` and press enter is it changing it too `06-Jan-15`

Comment: Excel takes the input in an expected format (locale).  Your custom formatting of that input doesn't change how Excel parses it.  I.e., you're able to customize the output, but the input is still read in the same way.

Comment: How can i change the way the input is read

Comment: You'll likely have to go to your Windows/System settings and change it from there.  Try this first though - after you have your data in there, highlight the range and go to Data tab --> Text to Columns --> Keep "delimited", click "Next", click "Next" again, then in the "Column data format" area, choose "Date: DMY".  Then click "Finish".  That should update the values and show them in the `dd-mmm-yy` format (it's worked for me in the past when the dates are being weird).

Comment: @BruceWayne Already done this and made no difference

Comment: Have you tried changing the system date format? That's the only other thing I can think of at the moment.

Comment: the system (and the office dictionary) are all set to UK.

Comment: Unfortunately, Excel sometimes tries to be "intelligent" and makes wrong guesses about entered dates. The exchange of date formats is an old ongoing problem in the field of IT.

Comment: @SQLPolice Yeh this one was a strange one, however it transpired it was some rogue vba code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the **Locale** in the Format Cells Dialogue. I would guess that you have it set to the English (U.S.) format, instead of the (more logical) English (U.K.) format. See here:

[image]

Comment: this was the first thing i tried and A. even in a standard format the date changes back when i press enter and B. this isnt the format i want (dd-mmm-yy)

Comment: Or if its not necessary to have values ad date, setting to "text" should also restrict Excel formatter :)

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be some poor code in the VBA which was setting the format regardless of the front end settings.

Keeping this here for future reference.